# Measurement of probability from nine consecutive integers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three distinct positive integers are selected at random from 9 consecutive positive integers. What is the probability that their average is also an integer?

Is there any way to find it efficiently? I'd taken example of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ then there are a lot of combinations to give a number divisible by three which give an integer average value. It's difficult to find the way :D

Thank you.

Comment: Is this selection with or without replacement?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, without replacement

Comment: I'd taken example of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 then there are a lot of combinations to give a number divisible by three which give an integer average value. It's difficult to find the way :D

Comment: This only depends on what your picks are modulo $3$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown can you describe it in detail please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be three each of integers that are $0,1,2\bmod3$ in the given range. The admissible selections sum to $0\bmod3$, of which there are four ways to achieve it:
$$000\ (1\text{ selection})$$
$$111\ (1)$$
$$222\ (1)$$
$$012\ (27)$$
This gives 30 admissible selections out of $\binom93=84$ total selections, for a probability of $\frac{30}{84}=\frac5{14}$.

Comment: Can you describe how you get 1,1,1 and 27 ?
I've understand all other things

Comment: @SagarGautam concretely, using 1 to 9, there are exactly three numbers $0\bmod3$ (3, 6, 9), so only one way to choose all of them in one selection (the 000 case). Same for 111 (1, 4, 7) and 222 (2, 5, 8). For 012, we are free to choose one of the $0\bmod3$ numbers, and likewise for the 1 and 2 modulo 3 numbers, giving $3×3×3=27$ ways.

Answer (score 1):

The average is an integer if the sum is divisible by $3$, which is the case if and only if the residues of the integers modulo $3$ are either all different or all the same. The probability for them to be all different is

$$
\frac{\binom31^3}{\binom93}=\frac9{28}\;,
$$

and the probability for them to all be the same is

$$
\frac3{\binom93}=\frac1{28}\;.
$$

Thus the probability for the average to be an integer is $\frac{1+9}{28}=\frac5{14}$.